# jQuery XML parsing: select all nodes containing a certain tag with a certain value

Tags: jquery, xml-parsing

Let's say the XPath is "/bookstore/book[price=35.00]" (from the w3 example).

Here's a fiddle with how far I've got so far.

https://jsfiddle.net/npvgfzwc/

```
    var name = src.find("bookstore book:has(price:contains('35.00')) title").text();
```

I can get it to select books with a price *containing* 35.00, but can't find a way to make it match exactly that. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use:

```
var name=src.find("bookstore book price").filter(function(){
  return $(this).text()=="35.00"
}).prev().text();
$('#blah').text(name);
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mve8cgs8/)**